# CSS - filter brightness but only for the background color

Tags: css

I want to be able to dim the color of a div, but not darken the text.

I am using the css filter property: brightness(70%); but the white text that I have in the div turns gray. How can I make it so that only the background is darkened without affecting the text?

```
<div class="brightness_70">
 <div>
  <h1 class="welcome_portal">Welcome:)</h1>
 </div>
</div>

.brightness_70 {
    filter: brightness(70%);
}
```

Comment: Depending on where your background color ist defined, you can just apply the filter to that element. If it is the same element or parent element, you should consider moving the background-color to a seperate element below your `h1`. Css filters are always applied to the targeted element, and all its (nested) child elements.

Comment: And how can I make it apply to the main one and not to the nested one?

Comment: This will only work if you move your h1 element outside of the element were the filter is appllied to. You cannot undo filters that are applied from above, as they are applied to the whole element.